MapBox Android Simulation - GPS location from extended settings instead of hard coded
In Android Mapbox Navigation: there is code part which start the navigation replay from a hard coded custom GPS lat,long position here
We want to achieve to able to run simulation from custom points but not hard coded way. (we try to avoid code re-compilation)

I tried to get the GPS position in this place from LocationManager, but I got nullpointerexception. (I guess not initializet in this phase)

I tried to get GPS localtion from LocationManager at the end of oncreate function, but the same NPE result

I tried to observe location updates, and when the first GPS position ready I wanted to us it. But not fired, I feel this is a hen-egg problem


Is there any possible solution for this?
